# Performance testing in C++ project

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance-testing, valgrind

I wrote a project in c++ with 10 threads. One thread loads the data into memory(write the buffer) and other 9 threads are simultaneously read the buffer and store data in SQLite database, All threads are handled with the mutex to avoid conflicts.

Now I need to evaluate the performance of this project such as time to success per threads, memory usages etc. How can I go it in c++ environment? I used **Valgrind** to check these. But I think it not working.

This is the code I run with Valgrind,

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./executable
```

It gives a message like this,

```
callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./monerosci 
==24262== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24262== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24262== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24262== Command: ./monerosci
==24262== 

valgrind: m_syswrap/syswrap-linux.c:5361 
(vgSysWrap_linux_sys_fcntl_before): Assertion 'Unimplemented 
functionality' failed.
valgrind: valgrind

host stacktrace:
==24262==    at 0x38083F48: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==24262==    by 0x38084064: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==24262==    by 0x380841F1: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==24262==    by 0x380FB399: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==24262==    by 0x380D6234: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==24262==    by 0x380D2D2A: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==24262==    by 0x380D43DE: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==24262==    by 0x380E3946: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
```

How can I test the performance of the project in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems there's two separate problems here:

1) `memcheck` is failing to run due to a bug or some limitation. Apparently one variation of a `fcntl` call is not supported by your version of valgrind. Maybe you should reduce the code size, remove libraries, until you can pinpoint which call is triggering this problem. Or just run it under a different version of valgrind. However, I think `memcheck` will not give you the data you want...

2) `memcheck` is not a tool for profiling. Valgrind is composed of several different tools that can be switched by using the `--tool` parameter. [Here's](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) an overview of them. The one that most likely will give you the info you want is `callgrind`.